# Quero que minha variável sempre seja inteira

Tags: python-3.x

Gente preciso sair de um drama em que não consigo finalizar minha lógica sem ficar preso em condição dentro de condição, o código faz parte de um jogo da velha que estou aperfeiçoando, minha condição no código abaixo diz que o valor da entrada do usuário tem que ser NUMÉRICO e se for numérico tem que ser <= 8, caso não for numérico ele entra no loop para o usuário digitar novamente.

```
a = input('Jogador "X", onde pretende fazer a jogada? ')

    q = 1

    while q == 1:

        if a.isnumeric() and int(a) <= 8:
            a = int(a)
            break
        else:
            a = input('Jogador "X", digite um número de 0 a 8: ')

    if int(a) == int(b) or j[a] == 'X' or j[a] == 'O':

        while int(a) == int(b) or j[a] == 'X' or j[a] == 'O':   #essa linha é responsável pelo erro

            a = input('Jogador "X" por favor, escolha outro campo: ')

            if a.isnumeric() and int(a) <= 8:
                a = int(a)

            else:
                a = input('Jogador "X", digite um número de 0 a 8: ')

    j[a] = 'X'insira o código aqui
```

Comment: da onde vem a variável B e qual erro você tá enfrentando exatamente?

Comment: então o jogo completo está aqui https://repl.it/JxEi/4 , digite a sequencia de entradas 1, 1, 1, ', '    .......eu quero que o filtro não deixe passar se o usuário querer digitar uma aspa ou algo que não seja numérico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa fazer dois whiles um dentro do outro. O primeiro while será para validar o movimento/jogada, e o segundo para validar o input. Ou seja, para toda jogada, você vai verificar primeiro a entrada e depois se o campo do jogo está livre.

Isso resultará em algo parecido com isso:

```
while c <= 10:
    if c % 2 == 1:
        a = input('Jogador "X", onde pretende fazer a jogada? ')
        while True:
            while True:
                if a.isnumeric() and int(a) <= 8:
                    a = int(a)
                    break
                else:
                    a = input('Jogador "X", digite um número de 0 a 8: ')
            if j[a] != ' ':
                a = input('Jogador "X" por favor, escolha outro campo: ')
            else:
                break
        j[a] = 'X'
```

Você também tem a opção de definir uma função para verificar sua jogada.

```
def check(ipt):
    if ipt.isnumeric() and int(ipt) <= 8:
        ipt = int(ipt)
        if j[ipt] != " ":
            return "Campo já preenchido"
        return True
    return "Erro de input"

while c <= 10:
    if c % 2 == 1:
        a = input('Jogador "X", onde pretende fazer a jogada? ')
        while check(a) is not True:
            if check(a) == "Erro de input":
                a = input('Jogador "X", digite um número de 0 a 8: ')
            elif check(a) == "Campo já preenchido":
                a = input('Jogador "X" por favor, escolha outro campo: ')
        a = int(a)
        j[a] = 'X'
```

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/KAS7/1)

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito principalmente na parte de definir a função..